# Why does this object contain `true` instead of the user name when logged?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got an array with user info and user comments and I want to find which user left a specific comment. But when my function runs the `console.log` prints out this object:

```js
{id: '7f053852-7440-4e44-838c-ddac24611050', firstName: false, lastName: 'Burke'}
```

and I’ve tried another comment but the results are not much different:

```js
{id: 'b4a306cb-8b95-4f85-b9f8-434dbe010985', firstName: true, lastName: 'Marshall'}
```

Here my code:

```js
var users = [
  {
    id: "88f24bea-3825-4237-a0d1-efb6b92d37a4",
    firstName: "Sam",
    lastName: "Hughes",
  },
  {
    id: "2a35032d-e02b-4508-b3b5-6393aff75a53",
    firstName: "Terri",
    lastName: "Bishop",
  },
  {
    id: "7f053852-7440-4e44-838c-ddac24611050",
    firstName: "Jar",
    lastName: "Burke",
  },
  {
    id: "b4a306cb-8b95-4f85-b9f8-434dbe010985",
    firstName: "Some string",
    lastName: "Marshall"
  }
];
const comments = [
  {
    userId: "88f24bea-3825-4237-a0d1-efb6b92d37a4",
    text: "Great Job!"
  },
  {
    userId: "7f053852-7440-4e44-838c-ddac24611050",
    text: "Well done, I think I understand now!",
  },
  {
    userId: "e789565f-fa5a-4d5e-8f6c-dd126cf995be",
    text: "How do you do that? ",
  },
  {
    userId: "7f053852-7440-4e44-838c-ddac24611050",
    text: "OK great thanks"
  },
  {
    userId: "b4a306cb-8b95-4f85-b9f8-434dbe010985",
    text: "Cool, thanks!"
  },
  {
    userId: "9e525c2d-6fcd-4d88-9ac4-a44eaf3a43e6",
    text: "Nice one "
  }
];
var getuserbycom = users.find((user) => user.id === comments.find((comment) => comment.text === "Cool, thanks!").userId);

console.log(getuserbycom);
```

Comment: _“But when my function runs the console.log […]”_ — Where is the code with the `console.log`?

Comment: I just edit the question, the console.log its placed after I defined the function

Comment: This isn’t reproducible. You’ve mutated `users` somewhere along the way.

Comment: thank you, i found it

Answer (score 0):

```
function findComment(comment) {
    return comments.find(userComment => userComment.text === comment)
}
```

You will get the `user` Object. After that you can use the `useId` as required